# Swapping the contents of two files on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I have two different files used for configuring a certain program I run.  They are the same except for a few lines.  The easiest way I found to do this was with a simple swap using three copy, *cp*, commands. Is there a better way to do this? I am running in a CentOS system.

As stated above, this is the script I came up with (file names would be more descriptive in use, but removed for privacy).

```
cp file1.txt temp.txt
cp file2.txt file1.txt
cp temp.txt file2.txt
rm temp.txt
```

Comment: Why copying? It would be cheaper to use `mv`, at least as long the files reside on the same file system. To avoid race conditions (in case two instances of your script run in parallel), I would generate the name of the tempfile dynamically, for instance `temp.$$` instead of `temp.txt`. And I would execute each subsequent command only if the previous one succeeded. You know: The devil never sleeps.

Comment: One more thing to consider: What about the timestamp of the files after the exchange? Should they be related somehow to the original timestamps (maybe exchanged as well)? Your question would be more clear if you would describe precisely the desired effect of the operation.

Comment: I just need to swap the contents.  Timestamp is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (no proof here) that using `mv` would be more efficient, as you would just change the name of the files, instead of copying them.

```
mv file1.txt temp.txt
mv file2.txt file1.txt
mv temp.txt file2.txt
```

And that's one command less than yours.

Comment: Ah I see, so does ```mv``` command then also get rid of the *temp.txt* file when used in this manner?

Comment: @MoonlightCrusader basically, `mv` is like renaming a file

Comment: @MoonlightCrusader No, it just renames it. As Fravadona said, mv renames the file, without moving any data, while cp moves data from a point to another.